What does 0 mean next to the db2sysc process?
On Db2 v11.5 on Linux if I execute a command to check if database instance is up and running:
ps -e -o command | grep db2sysc
the output is:
db2sysc 0

What does the number 0 means? I am just asking because, maybe this could be useful to use in bash scripting.

The number 0 after db2sysc represents the database partition number (or instance member number) in a Db2 multi-partitioned environment. In this case, 0 indicates that the instance is running on partition (or member) number 0, which is typically the default partition for a single-partition Db2 environment.
If you are using a Db2 instance with a single partition (i.e., not a Db2 pureScale or partitioned database), the db2sys 0 process will be the only one running. In a multi-partition environment, you will see several db2sysc processes with different numbers, one per partition.

We always use Db2 instance with single partition, that is why I only observed db2sysc 0. This seams pretty useful info for scripting. Thanks.

The statement about the ‘0’ in a non-partitioned instance is incorrect.  The ‘0’ does not provide any information about the health of the db2sysc process.  It’s literally just the database partition/member number (even when there’s only 1 database partition/member)

Is this "0" somehow related to db2node.cfg file setting?
